# Exiting a clock loop in Logisim

Tags: circuit-design, flipflop, logisim

I've been trying to get a traffic light simulation working on Logisim but I've run into some issues.

The way the circuit works is that I default to the green light, and when I press a button (represented as a pin), I switch to the yellow light for two clock cycles and then to the red light for eight cycles before going all the way back to the green light and waiting for the button to be pressed again.

The way both the yellow lights work is with a counter (either set to 1 or 3 bits) with a clock as the clock signal. The output of the counter goes to a decoder that checks for the last digit (either 1 or 7) and connects it to the data input in a T flip-flop, and the Q output of that flip-flop corresponds to the light in question.

Here's my current implementation:

[image: Here's my current implementation]

I have all the individual components working, but I was wondering how I could break the cycle for the yellow and red lights, to cycle to the next light (yellow to red) or to restart completely (red to green).

EDIT: Here follows the ASM graph I have designed for this circuit
Note: There are two circuits to be implemented, and in this post I am only referring to the Vehiche's circuit, because I feel like the transition between states would work similarly even if in different circuits.
[image: ASM Model of the circuit]

Comment: It isn't clear to me, yet. In one place you write about a yellow light. But later say "both the yellow lights" which reads as a plural to me (more than one.) Also, it sounds like you have just one push button to use. And that it triggers movement to the yellow light, then movement to the red light, then movement back to the green light. Same button? Or different buttons? The schematic I see above doesn't look at all right to me. But perhaps just because it is done as individual sections. Is it that these need to be combined in some way? If so, why didn't you combine them? Not enough training?

Comment: @periblepsis its just a single button for those interactions, and yes, I did not connect them because I can't figure out how to, that is why I made the post in the first place.
Additionally, the circuit is composed of a Green light, a Yellow light and a Red light, and I'm trying to go in between them.

Comment: Have you developed any kind of state table for this? Or are you just operating completely in the dark about how to proceed on it? I'm both shocked and not-shocked about education these days. But I would like to know what you can and cannot manage on your own, so that I have a foundation to work from if I decide to try helping.

Comment: I did not, because I had no clue on how to, and thought it'd be easier to just start trying out circuits in Logisim. 
I did make an ASM model for it though.
As soon as I read the description I wasn't sure on how I could proceed with a state table, so I went on to Logisim directly...

Comment: It might help if you posted up what you have. Everything you have produced that might help clarify. And an abstract state machine model would definitely help clarify details.

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll edit the post with the ASM model I have done for the circuit @periblepsis

Comment: Also, do you have to use T FFs? Or is JK or D also allowed? And do you care how many FFs? Can they be wasted? Or are you looking for a minimum FF design?

Comment: I can also use JK or D FFs and yes, I can waste FFs, I only tried with T because it seemed to work alright for the purpose I was pursuing

Comment: Well, get the ASM added. Or something. I think this can be kept pretty simple: 4 JK FFs.

Comment: I have just edited the post. @periblepsis

Comment: Well, that helps. And it's nothing like I expected to see. There are two sets of lights, one for vehicles and another set for pedestrians. So I think it is important that you added all this. I think I get the idea of the pedestrian sensor. But how does the car sensor play into all this? Is there a different behavior if there is no car sensor activity? Or if there is? Does it stay for pedestrians until a car is detected at a stop? Or does it always return to a default priority for vehicles?

Comment: Well, I have implemented the sensor as a pin in Logisim for ease of use, but its behaviour is the following:
By default the car's light is green, if the sensor activates by detecting a car speeding (I have no limit for this, hence the usage of a pin), the light should change to yellow for two clock cycles, and then to red, for eight.
So I have no gauge on if there isnt car sensor activity, its implied that there is, simply.
And yes, it returns to default priority for vehicles.

Comment: I think I understand that the default is for vehicles. So if a pedestrian wants to cross, their cycle is fixed and the system ***always*** returns to a state where cars are allowed to continue through. So I take it that if a pedestrian wants to cross, it switches over only for a short time and then returns to allowing cars. But what is meant by English "a car speeding"? And why is a car sensor needed at all? Doesn't sound like it is. There's no use for it. It does nothing.

Comment: Well to that last question my honest answer is, I also have no clue, my assignment contemplated the sensor and the button as mandatory in it, so I suppose even if it doesn't make sense, it still has to be there...
Also, by "speeding" I meant it going over the speed limit (now you ask, what's that limit, and my answer is, there isn't one, because I wasnt given that information at all.)
Thank you for the patience and help!

Comment: Thanks. But if you don't have any idea what the car sensor does, then neither do I. So far as I can tell it doesn't matter if there is a car, or if the car is going fast or not, or anything at all. Nothing changes. Because of that, a design cannot include it. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: The car sensor is the input for the cars' traffic light to change, from green, to yellow, to red, and back to green again

Comment: Why would a car sensor cause the light to go red? A car sensor should just say "stay green". Or is this a 4-way stop with pedestrians, too? This may be getting very complex if you have to deal with cars crossing each other, pedestrians crossing either way, etc.

Comment: Now, it's possible that a car would cause the light to go green IF AND ONLY IF the pedestrian sensor caused the light to change to RED for cars and to STAY RED until a car arrived at the stop. Then it could make sense. But you said that isn't what happens.

Comment: Oh no, its a straight road, with a pedestrian cross.
The car sensor detects any car that could be going over the speed limit in order to switch the cars' lights, and if a pedestrian wants to cross the road, they press the button and that triggers the lights of the cars' traffic light to change (from green to red) and for the pedestrians' lights to change (from red to green)
I hope this made it a bit more clear...

Comment: No. I guess it isn't clear to me. I guess I've spent enough time trying to follow. I have most of it. But not enough. So I'm holding short. Clearly we've reached a dead-end in our ability to communicate. I could put more time in. But that's not my job. It's your question. I need to be able to sit down completely by myself and use little pieces of paper and be able to work out all the behavior. But I know I can't with what I know at this time.

Comment: But is there any way you can advise me on how to move forward with this?
Should I revamp the whole circuit or can  I work off of what I've got?
Or any tips on how to proceed with the whole implementation of it, but i suppose that's not on you to tell me, thank you anyways!

Comment: I should add, those two circuits in the ASM model are to be working indepedentaly and then to be joined, but that's not what I was worrying about at the moment ^^'

Comment: I honestly don't know what to suggest. What I don't know could mean substantial changes, so anything I might think right now could be totally wrong in the end. If you were to limit the question to just one aspect that were crystal clear in its behavior, sure. But I fear that it won't really help you to merge these. There is NO QUESTION IN MY MIND that these are INTERACTING SYSTEMS. That much seems clear. And therefore you CANNOT IGNORE one while working on the other. It just doesn't work like that. The need for the car's red to run long enough to allow the peds to cycle, itself, is enough.

Comment: That is true, they are interacting systems indeed...

Comment: So. I do have a conclusion. You do not know enough about this problem, yet. So sit down with it on a piece of paper. Forget digital logic. It does not matter right now. You want to sit down and write rules good enough that this could be a paper-game played by people with chips and cards on a table. Once you work this out good enough that you could sell this game to others and they could play it correctly, then and only then can you write this up well enough here to start considering logic. We live with computers roday. But act as if you were living in the 1800's. No computers. Just you.

Comment: This is about your ability to turn this problem into a game that can be played. Until then, it's nothing.

Comment: OKay, I think I got it, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a solution for you. Quite frankly, I don't know what would be a solution since you can't describe the problem in sufficient detail.

But let's say that the flow was something like this:

[image]

It stays in the top state until a pedestrian presses their button. Then it immediately transitions to the next stage. At the end, vehicles are guaranteed at least 8 cycles of **green** before the pedestrian button is again observed.

If so, the following might satisfy me:

[image]

The clock is blocked when in the initial state until the **PED** button is pressed. Once that happens, nothing can interrupt the cycle until it is completed. Then and only then can the **PED** button be once again observed to trigger another cycle.

You may watch the MP4 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5T8TUUqOlrM). (One cycle per second.)

I'm offering this to get you focused on defining your problem. It's not defined well, yet. But perhaps the above will show enough to suggest certain ways/approaches that can be used to solve problems similar to this one.